# $f'''(0)$ of $f(x)=\sin x/x,x \neq 0,1, x=0$

Tags: derivatives

I want to find the Taylor polynomial at zero for  $f(x)=\sin x/x \ \text{if} \ x \neq 0, 1 \ \text{if} \ x=0$ and struggle to find $f''(0).$  I can't just differentiate $\sin x/x$ because we are considering $0$.I have $f'(0)=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x/x-1}{x}=0$ (l'Hopital) but how do I find the second derivative, I need a general expression for the derivative?

Comment: If $x\ne0$, $$f'(x)=\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}$$ hence $$f''(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^3}$$ Can you compute this limit? Knowing that $$1-\cos x\sim\frac{x^2}2\qquad x-\sin x\sim\frac{x^2}6$$ suffices...

Comment: If you want to find the Taylor series why don't you just divide the Taylor series for $\sin x$ by $x$?

Comment: Are you asking for the second derivative or for the third derivative?

Comment: The second derivative is enough. Doesn't $\frac{\cos x}{x^2}$ as $x \to 0$ diverge?

Comment: Yes -- and this is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: A better method is to note that function is even( check domain). what does that imply? I am sure you can take it from there. Keep note of differentiability of function using first principle, first